# How to make Wget handle an HTTP 100-Continue response?

Tags: http, wget

I am trying to POST a HTML (contained in a file) to a URL using [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) like this:

```
wget -O- --debug
     --header=Content-Type:text/html
     --post-file=index.html
     http://localhost/www/encoder.ashx
```

The URL to which the HTML is being posted is a Web application end-point implemented using ASP.NET. The server replies with a [100 (Continue)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.1.1) response and Wget simply stops dead in its tracks rather than continuing with the *real* response that *should* follow next.

**Can Wget be somehow told to hanlde a 100 (Continue) response or is this some well-known limitation of the tool?**

Notes:

- I noticed that Wget never sends
  the `Expect: 100-Continue` header so
  technically the server should not be
  issuing a 100 (Continue) response.

  **UPDATE:** Looks like this is possible, as per [§8.2.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3) 
  of  [RFC 2616 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html):

  > An origin server SHOULD NOT send a 100 (Continue) response if
  >   the request message does not include an Expect request-header
  >   field with the "100-continue" expectation, and MUST NOT send a
  >   100 (Continue) response if such a request comes from an HTTP/1.0
  >   (or earlier) client. There is an exception to this rule: for
  >   compatibility with RFC 2068, *a server MAY send a 100 (Continue)
  >   status in response to an HTTP/1.1 PUT or POST request that does
  >   not include an Expect request-header field with the "100-
  >   continue" expectation.* This exception, the purpose of which is
  >   to minimize any client processing delays associated with an
  >   undeclared wait for 100 (Continue) status, applies only to
  >   HTTP/1.1 requests, and not to requests with any other HTTP-
  >   version value.
- [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) has no problems with such a transaction.
  It send an `Expect: 100-Continue` header
  and continued with 100 (Continue) response
  on to the real one.

For more information, here is the full debug trace of the transaction from the invocation shown above:

```
Setting --post-file (postfile) to index.html
Setting --header (header) to Content-Type:text/html
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.10 on Windows.

--13:29:17--  http://localhost/www/encoder.ashx
           => `-'
Resolving localhost... seconds 0.00, 127.0.0.1
Caching localhost => 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... seconds 0.00, connected.
Created socket 296.
Releasing 0x01621a10 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
POST /www/encoder.ashx HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.10
Accept: */*
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 30984

---request end---
[writing POST file index.html ... done]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2008 11:29:17 GMT
Content-Length: 0

---response end---
100 Continue
Closed fd 296
13:29:17 ERROR 100: Continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source code to wget for Windows, and as far as I can tell the debug output is coming from the generic error condition when wget fails to parse the response properly. Looks like this is just a limitation of wget, so you'll probably have to use curl or some other method to avoid encountering this issue.